# Tomcat: Different welcome-file for local and live setup

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, web.xml

I'm a beginner with Tomcat/Java; I have a simple web application for which I would like to show a different `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml` depending on whether the application is being run locally development or deployed live.

Right now I have:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

For local development I would like the `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml` to be `index-dev.html` for development and `index-live.html` for the deployed live application. Reason being I want to load different `*.css` and `*.js` depending on whether I'm local or live.

Any way in which I can achieve this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option: make a jsp file as a welcome page.

In that jsp file analyze current client location (local computer or not), and forward to the relevant page.

**ADDITIONAL EDIT:**

Your jsp has a predefined `request` object.

Use it to get client ip, like that:

```
<%
    String remoteIp = request.getRemoteAddr();
%>
```

Compare it with localhost address, which can be obtained via:

```
<%
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String localhostIp = address.getHostAddress();
%>
```

And use `jsp:forward` to forward to a relevant page.

```
<%
    // getting jsp (servlet) client ip
    String remoteIp = request.getRemoteAddr();

    // getting local ip
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String localhostIp = address.getHostAddress();

    // checking and forwarding
    if(localhostIp.equals(remoteIp)){
%>
     <jsp:forward page="localhost.html"/>
<%}else{%>
    <jsp:forward page="remote.html"/>
<%}%>
```

**Additional edit:**

Make sure that localhostIp contains only IP address, otherwise use `String` methods to get substring with ip-address inside.

Comment: Thanks, any useful links / code samples for the Tomcat/Java beginner?

Comment: On my local machine `localhostIp` is `127.0.1.1` and address is `name-of-my-machine/127.0.1.1 `. I ended up using `request.getRequestURL()` and if it `startswith` `http://localhost:8080/` then it's local.

Comment: Please note, that Tomcat can be configured to work with another port than 8080. And on another Tomcat instance with different (non-default) port settings your comparison won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks; indeed I changed the logic to check simply for the presence of substring `localhost` and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a header page (which is going to be included in all the pages including welcome page). Write a `<c:if>` to do a simple check for you. I don't think servlet spec supports different welcome pages based of requesting machine's IP address. Ideally any web-app is suppose to be serving the same pages from where ever it is accessed

Answer (score 1):

Live should always have a apache httpd who proxy-redirect to the tomcat.

This have multiple pros:

- if the tomcat is down, you can define a "please be patient/come back later" info.html
- using awstats you can analyze the traffic
- You can define live JS/CSS-directorys to discharge tomcat

Regards

Comment: +1ed; but I have no Apache in front of Tomcat (won't even have it in production, it's Tomcat7 not earlier versions)